# Placing JLabel, JButton etc. in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, layout-manager

at the begginning i want to say im Polish guy, so sorry if my english will be bad... and my code have polish names.

I am doing calculator in active window, but i have many issues and i can not solve it. I want to have  Label and TextField in the top, RadioBoxes and TextArea in the middle and CheckBoxes and Buttons on the bottom, just like on this sketch:

[image]

BorderLayour should help me, but if i am changing FlowLayout to Border i have that view:

[image]

One BIG closing...

and with FlowLayout it looks like this:

[image]

I am sending the code and i hope you will find the way how to help me.. !

code:

```
    package kalkulator;

import javaapplication7.Input;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;



public class DialogDemo extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{


    //Pole tekstowe jednolinijkowe
    JLabel etykietaTekstWe1    = new JLabel("Pierwsza liczba:");
    JLabel etykietaTekstWe2    = new JLabel("Druga liczba:");
    JTextField poleTekstWe1  = new JTextField("",10);
    JTextField poleTekstWe2  = new JTextField("",10);

    //Pole tekstowe wielolinijkowe
    JLabel etykietaTekstWy   = new JLabel("Wynik:");
    JTextArea poleTekstWy = new JTextArea("",10,20);     

    //Trzy przyciki
    JButton przyciskLicz = new JButton("Licz"); 
    JButton przyciskCzysc = new JButton("Czysc");
    JButton przyciskZamknij = new JButton("Zamknij");

    //Trzy przyciski wyboru jeden z wielu
    JLabel etykietaOdp   = new JLabel("");
    JRadioButton dodawanie = new JRadioButton("[ + ] Dodawanie",true);
    JRadioButton odejmowanie = new JRadioButton("[ - ] Odejmowanie",false);
    JRadioButton mnozenie = new JRadioButton("[ * ] Mnozenie",false);
    JRadioButton dzielenie = new JRadioButton("[ / ] Dzielenie",false);

    //Cztery przyciski wyboru kilka z wielu
    JLabel etykietaCzyszczenie   = new JLabel("");
    JCheckBox czyszczenie1 = new JCheckBox("Wyczysc liczby"); 
    JCheckBox czyszczenie2 = new JCheckBox("Wyczysc wynik");

    long czasStart;

    public DialogDemo()
    {
        //Odczytanie czasu poczatkowego 
        czasStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

        //Ustawienie managera ukladu calego okna
        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,20,30));      




                JMenuBar pasekMenu = new JMenuBar();
                JMenu menuPierwsze = new JMenu("Plik");
                pasekMenu.add(menuPierwsze);

                JMenuItem wyjdz = new JMenuItem("Zamknij");
                menuPierwsze.add(wyjdz);
                wyjdz.addActionListener(this);

                JMenu menuDrugie = new JMenu("Edycja");
                pasekMenu.add(menuDrugie);

                JMenuItem czysc = new JMenuItem("Czysc");
                menuDrugie.add(czysc);
                czysc.addActionListener(this);

                JMenuItem odczyt = new JMenuItem("Licz");
                menuDrugie.add(odczyt);
                odczyt.addActionListener(this);

                JMenu menuTrzecie = new JMenu("Pomoc");
                pasekMenu.add(menuTrzecie);

                setJMenuBar(pasekMenu);


        //-------------------------------------

        //Wstawienie panelu z jednolinijkowym polem tekstowym

        JPanel panelTextWe1 = new JPanel();
        panelTextWe1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panelTextWe1.add(etykietaTekstWe1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panelTextWe1.add(poleTekstWe1,BorderLayout.CENTER);

                JPanel panelTextWe2 = new JPanel();
        panelTextWe2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panelTextWe2.add(etykietaTekstWe2,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panelTextWe2.add(poleTekstWe2,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        getContentPane().add(panelTextWe1);
        getContentPane().add(panelTextWe2);

        //-------------------------------------

        //Wstawienie panelu z przyciskami wyboru kilka z wielu

        Box boxRGrupa = Box.createVerticalBox(); //Pionowy (kolumnowy) manager ulozenia
        boxRGrupa.add(etykietaOdp);

        boxRGrupa.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10)); //Dodanie rozporki (przestrzeni) o wielkosci
                                                    //10 pikseli pomiedzy etykieta etykietaOdp 
                                                    // a przyciskiem przyciskA

        ButtonGroup bGrupa = new ButtonGroup();


        bGrupa.add(dodawanie);
        boxRGrupa.add(dodawanie);       
        bGrupa.add(odejmowanie);
        boxRGrupa.add(odejmowanie); 
        bGrupa.add(mnozenie);
        boxRGrupa.add(mnozenie);    
        bGrupa.add(dzielenie);
        boxRGrupa.add(dzielenie);

        getContentPane().add(boxRGrupa);

        //-------------------------------------

        //Wstawienie panelu z przyciskami wyboru kilka z wielu

        Box boxCGrupa = Box.createHorizontalBox(); //Poziomy (wierszowy) manager ulozenia
        boxCGrupa.add(etykietaCzyszczenie);
        czyszczenie1.setSelected(true);     
        boxCGrupa.add(czyszczenie1);
        czyszczenie2.setSelected(false);
        boxCGrupa.add(czyszczenie2);            

        getContentPane().add(boxCGrupa);

        //-------------------------------------

        //Wstawienie panelu z wielowierszowym polem tekstowym

        JPanel panelTextWy = new JPanel();
        panelTextWy.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panelTextWy.add(etykietaTekstWy,BorderLayout.NORTH);        
        panelTextWy.add(new JScrollPane(poleTekstWy),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        poleTekstWy.setEditable(false);     

        getContentPane().add(panelTextWy);

        //-------------------------------------

        //Wstawienie przyciskow

        getContentPane().add(przyciskLicz) ;
        getContentPane().add(przyciskCzysc);
        getContentPane().add(przyciskZamknij);


        //Ustawienie sluchacza dla wszystkich przyciskow

        przyciskLicz.addActionListener(this);
        przyciskCzysc.addActionListener(this);           
        przyciskZamknij.addActionListener(this);
    }


    //Obsluga zdarzen klikniecia na przycisk
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent zdarzenie)  
    {   
        if (zdarzenie.getActionCommand().equals("Licz"))
        {
            poleTekstWy.setText(""); //Wyczyszczenie pola wyjsciowego

            String tekst = poleTekstWe1.getText();  
            poleTekstWy.append("Tekst: "+tekst+"\n"); //Dodanie teksty wejsciowego

            //------------------------------------------------------            

            //Wstawienie informacji o wybranych jezykach

            poleTekstWy.append("Jezyki: ");
            if (czyszczenie1.isSelected()) poleTekstWy.append(czyszczenie1.getText()+" ");
            if (czyszczenie2.isSelected()) poleTekstWy.append(czyszczenie2.getText()+" ");
            poleTekstWy.append("\n");

            //------------------------------------------------------

          //Wstawienie informacji o wybranej (jednej) odpowiedzi jakiegos testu

            if (dodawanie.isSelected())
            {
                poleTekstWy.append(dodawanie.getText()+"\n");
            }
            else
                if (odejmowanie.isSelected())
                {
                    poleTekstWy.append(odejmowanie.getText()+"\n");                 
                }   
                    else
                                if (mnozenie.isSelected())
                               {
                                    poleTekstWy.append(mnozenie.getText()+"\n");                    
                                }   
                                else 
                                {
                                        poleTekstWy.append(dzielenie.getText()+"\n");
                                }
        }
        else
        {
            if (zdarzenie.getActionCommand().equals("Czysc"))       
            {
                //Przywrocenie poczatkowego stanu pola wyjsciowego

                poleTekstWy.setText("");    
            }
            else
            {
                //Odczytanie czasu zakonczenia
                long czasStop = System.currentTimeMillis();

                //Obliczenie czasu uzywania programu
                long liczbaSekund = (czasStop-czasStart)/1000;
                this.setVisible(false);
                Input.showMessage("Czas uzywania programu w sekundach: "+liczbaSekund);

                System.exit(0); //Zakonczenie pracy programu
            }
        }

        repaint();
    }


    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {               
        DialogDemo dialogDemo  = new DialogDemo();
        dialogDemo.setTitle("Kalkulatorek");
        dialogDemo.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        dialogDemo.setLocation(500,100);
        dialogDemo.setSize(600,700);        
        dialogDemo.setVisible( true );     
                dialogDemo.setResizable(true);
                dialogDemo.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600, 700));
    }   

    private void setMinimumSize() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try simplifying the layout by using panels as containers for individual areas.

For example, a top middle and bottom `JPanel` aligned using a `GridLayout`. Then within the top panel add your label and text field, instead of adding them directly to your main frame.

Of course there are different ways you could do it. This seems easiest because it lets you break up the big task of your entire layout into many smaller tasks, like how to align two text boxes within a panel.

Note that the panels can even be subdivided again. For example, the bottom panel could be divided into a checkboxes panel and a buttons panel, aligned to the left and the right using a `GridLayout`. Each time you subdivide your area you break your overall problem into smaller and more managable problems.

See this tutorial for a step by step walk through of how to use `GridLayout`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html

Comment: Adding a link to a tutorial or working code on how to use and align components in a JPanel using GrodLayout would be a good expansion to this answer.

Comment: @MasterBlaster definitely true. I added one

Comment: This is one of my 'copy/paste' comments that might help the OP. The 1st link is to a code example of combining layouts: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).